# How do you use the '-login' parameter in Steam's launch options? It only shows me the username, not the password

Tags: steam

I have one PC, one Windows user, two Steam accounts and want to change between them without having to enter the password each time. They don't have authenticator so that's a win-win.

I saw in another post that there was a command-line parameter to put in Steam's shortcut properties: `-login %u %p`, but here is the fun part, when I do `-login %username %password`, it opens Steam with `%username` in the text box and nothing on the password text box. So I remove the `%` and only the username appears in the Steam text box but nothing on the password. That has been my struggle, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that the password can't contain spaces or else it will bug the whole thing.

Comment: Did you try putting your password in quotes?

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for you all. you can create a steam shortcut on your desktop. and right click, go to Properties, and where it says Target, add at the end of the line after the Quotes,  -login yourUserName YourPassword
so it should look like this...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam.exe" -login GameCuunt itsAsecret
You can create a short cut for each account on your system, so if you have multiple accounts, or you share a computer with family, then create one for each account. remember to hit the logout when you exit, all done. Ill take my bow now. thanks.

Comment: OP's problem was that they had a space in their password and didn't know that they had to put quotes around it as a result. Similarly your suggestion will also not work as written for the same reason since it's basically exactly what OP said they were doing in the first place.

Comment: Well rather than adding a negative, you could have appreciated the clearer explanation I added. as you were right about the spaces, there are other posts than have tried to solve the problem but failed due to Steam changing their UI approach, and thinking about the simple users who may not know how to modify the Link, I was hoping to help those folk out.

Comment: Idk what you mean by "adding negative." The question is already about modifying the link and about a problem with the password. You answered a question that wasn't asked.